# Cache Thread, AsyncTask,Runnable class

Tags: android

Hello i am working on an application and i want it to run and offline. Is there any way to save an asynctask or a thread or a runnable class or something else to the internal storage so if the user dont have internet when the app detects internet connection then will execute the requests. Also i want to get back this classes objects when the app is closed and open again.

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>{

}

public class Thread1 extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
    }
}

public class Runnable implements java.lang.Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance